# PHP Form with PHP variable

Tags: php, get, tags

Im try to Programm some php.

i have a site : /index.php?go=newstep&callid=2

Where i put:

```
<form method="post" action="addnew.php"> <input type="text"  name="user" /> <input type="text"  name="text" /> <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($_GET["callid"]); ?>" name="test" />
```

This is because the next site "addnew.php" Needs the value "callid" from the link to ?go=newstep&callid=2

Why isn't it working?
Is there another way?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of working, what _is_ it doing?  If `callid` isn't passed to the URL of the calling page, it of course will not end up in the HTML. What's in the HTML source? Is this actually a PHP script, so the PHP is executed?  Do you have error reporting enabled?  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ... and you would see notices about an `undefined index 'callid'`

Comment: i just want if /index.php?go=newstep&callid=2 is 2 then the Field "test" gets the Value 2. If ist 444 then its 444.. just take the number from the URL and place it in a field.

Comment: Yes of course I understand that.  What I'm asking is what does the page source of the above form look like after supposedly rendered by PHP? Is the `value=` attribute blank? Does it errantly contain the full `<?php echo.... ?>`? What output do you get instead of what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use GET method, You can simply put Your variable as part of the link in action attribute. You don't have to use hidden input. Something like that:

```
action="addnew.php?callid=<?php echo $_GET['callid']; ?>"
```

Additionally, '"' char in attribute "value" may cause problems, because HTML may interpret it as end of the attribute value.

**EDIT:**
Exactly, You are using POST method in form, thus You are sending You variable, callid, by POST method now and it will be available in $_POST global array in addnew.php script, not in $_GET global array.

Comment: I'm glad to read. You can accept my answer to let future visitors know that the problem is solved (and also vote up instead of giving comments like this - as intended to comments) :)